# Android Pay QuickStart App - Error occurring while contacting Google

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, android-pay

I am attempting to run some sample Android Pay API code following the guide here:
https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/tutorial#setup

I'm using the sample Bikestore project provided in the link above. I followed the instructions to setup credentials/client ID for my app:

- Google Developers Console
- Created an Android Client ID for OAuth 2.0 using SHA1 fingerprint and entering the app's package name.

The app installs/runs successfully on my cell phone (Lollipop), however when attempting to "Login", it displays "***An error occurring while contacting Google. Please try again later***"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found a solution. In the sample project, the following dependencies were defined in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.8.0'
}
```

I added the following line and this seems to have fixed the connection issue:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```